# What is nextStater in React Router getComponents and where does it come from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is an example from the docs - where does `nextState` come from?

```
<Route path="courses/:courseId" getComponents={(nextState, cb) => {
  // do asynchronous stuff to find the components
  cb(null, {sidebar: CourseSidebar, content: Course})
}} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextState` is provided by router infrastructure and contains information about routes, params and location you are going to. This allows you to load components based on this info or pass custom properties or do whatever you want to with this information.

Simple example just for demo

```js
const { Router, Route, Link, hashHistory, Redirect } = ReactRouter

const App = props => (
  <div>
    I came from {`${props.from || ' nowhere'}`}
    <Link to={{pathname: '/', query: {from: 1}}}>State 1 </Link>
    <Link to={{pathname: '/', query: {from: 2}}}>State 2 </Link>
  </div>
)

const getComponent = (nextState, next) => {
  next(null, props => <App {...props} from={nextState.location.query.from} />)
}

const Root = () => (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" exact getComponent={getComponent}/>
    <Redirect from="/js" to="/" />
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@3.0.5/umd/ReactRouter.js"></script>


<div id="app">Loading</div>
```

Comment: thanks @yury! One question, why did you use have use `location`? Why isn't it just `nextState.query.form`? Is it just because you're getting props from a Link? Where else can you get props from?

Comment: I used it just for the sake of demo. There are better ways to get query params in components than that say using `withRouter`. But when you need to asynchronously load component based on those params you have to go this way. BTW you should keep in mind that `getComponent` was removed in react-router v4.

Answer (score 0):

Here next state is current state or initial state, in certain cases nextState refers to state which is not applied to view. so the nextState would be the most updated state.

for example you're setting 10 to var_x in state, previously it was 5.

in that case if you check nextState.var_x it would be 10 and this.state.var_x would be 5, after some time only the this.state.var_x will get updated and value would be 10.

Comment: Who gave the state to this route? Its parent route?

Comment: No, state is a local thing, so you have to set initailState. props can be set by parents